# Convert string containing decimal digit to unsigned char

Tags: c

I have an array of char (string) that contain a decimal number. 
How do I convert it to  unsigned char?

```
char  my_first_reg[2];
memcpy( my_first_reg, &my_str_mymatch[0], 1 );
my_first_reg[1] = '\0';
// now my_first_reg contain reg number ... how to convert to unsigned char
```

Comment: Why not `my_first_reg[0] = my_str_mymatch[0]`? Seems simpler with out using `memcpy`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - char isn't converting to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777117/c-char-isnt-converting-to-int)

Comment: Are you just trying to convert an ASCII value digit character to its numerical value?

Comment: Yes! ... just convert ASCII to unsigned char ... Im new to C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert `my_first_reg[0]` the ASCII character to its numeric value:

```
unsigned char value = my_first_reg[0] - '0';
```

This works because digits in the ASCII table are sequential:

```
    '0' = 0x30 = 48
    '1' = 0x31 = 49
    '2' = 0x32 = 50
    '3' = 0x33 = 51
    '4' = 0x34 = 52
    ...
    '9' = 0x39 = 57
```

---

The above is for converting one character.  If you have a longer string, consider using [`atoi()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi), [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol), [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf), or something similar.

Comment: This works because C requires the character set, be it ASCII or not, to have sequential digits `'0' ... '9'` characters.